# How do I reference a stored range to remove duplicates in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a couple of Excel sheets with between almost 200 to just over 500 rows containing duplicate values, which I need to remove. Since the number of rows varies quite a lot I need to get the function for removing the duplicates to use a dynamic range in some way. The solution I'm trying to use is:

```
Sub RemoveDup()

    Dim SR as Range

    Range(Cells(2,1), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Set SR = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Range(SR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'This doesn't work.

End Sub
```

The range-reference in my last statement doesn't work. I've tried to place it between " with and without &. But that didn't seem to be the trick either.

How should I reference to my stored range?

Comment: hi. this is a typo "Solumns:=1" or do you  have it on your code ?

Comment: No it's a typo here. In my code it sais "Columns". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following, this will get the Last Row with data in Column A, and then use that range to remove duplicates:

```
Sub RemoveDup()
    SR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column A

    Range("A2:A" & SR).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one follow up question. Have I understod your solution correct when I say that SR is no longer a range but a string which contain the rownumber? That can work for me as well, just so I know how to handle SR in the code that follows.

Comment: @MarJer SR would actually be a Long value, but in essence yes, it is a number representing the Last Row with data on column A. :)